# inconsistency in debug package in r

Tags: r, debugging

I am using the debug package in r to debug my code. I am testing the mtrace function in debug:

```
> require(debug)
Loading required package: debug
Loading required package: tcltk
> mtrace(ft.debug)
```

after that, the packages's author claims, if you invoke any function, a window will open where the code is displayed with numbered lines:

```
> fix(ft.debug)
```

ft.debug is test function whose code is:

```
function(){
              print("R is the most wonderful thing in the world")
}
```

but there is only the normal r function editor window: there is no numbered window.

How do I get the numbered window?

Comment: You didn't invoke the function.  That would be done by `ft.debug()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mtrace() only sets the debugging mode. You need to call the function after that:

```
require(debug)
ft.debug<- function(){
  print("R is the most wonderful thing in the world")
}
mtrace(ft.debug)
ft.debug()
```

[image]